# Difference between S3Client and AmazonS3Client

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Below is official aws sdk source regarding getting s3 object.

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/javav2/example_code/s3/src/main/java/com/example/s3/GetObjectData.java

```
public class GetObjectData {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String bucketName = args[0];
    String keyName = args[1];
    String path = args[2];

    ProfileCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = ProfileCredentialsProvider.create();
    Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
    S3Client s3 = S3Client.builder()
        .region(region)
        .credentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
        .build();

    getObjectBytes(s3,bucketName,keyName, path);
    s3.close();
}

// snippet-start:[s3.java2.getobjectdata.main]
public static void getObjectBytes (S3Client s3, String bucketName, String keyName, String path) {

    try {
        GetObjectRequest objectRequest = GetObjectRequest
            .builder()
            .key(keyName)
            .bucket(bucketName)
            .build();

        ResponseBytes<GetObjectResponse> objectBytes = s3.getObjectAsBytes(objectRequest);
        byte[] data = objectBytes.asByteArray();

        // Write the data to a local file.
        File myFile = new File(path );
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
        os.write(data);
        System.out.println("Successfully obtained bytes from an S3 object");
        os.close();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (S3Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
// snippet-end:[s3.java2.getobjectdata.main]
}
```

As you can see, there is `s3.close` in the middle of the code block.

However, I have the second code which does not close the `s3 client` in the official aws sdk as below.

the code below can be seen in the link here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/download-objects.htm

```
public class GetObject2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Regions clientRegion = Regions.DEFAULT_REGION;
        String bucketName = "*** Bucket name ***";
        String key = "*** Object key ***";

        S3Object fullObject = null, objectPortion = null, headerOverrideObject = null;
        try {
            AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                    .withRegion(clientRegion)
                    .withCredentials(new ProfileCredentialsProvider())
                    .build();

            // Get an object and print its contents.
            System.out.println("Downloading an object");
            fullObject = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, key));
            System.out.println("Content-Type: " + fullObject.getObjectMetadata().getContentType());
            System.out.println("Content: ");
            displayTextInputStream(fullObject.getObjectContent());

            // Get a range of bytes from an object and print the bytes.
            GetObjectRequest rangeObjectRequest = new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, key)
                    .withRange(0, 9);
            objectPortion = s3Client.getObject(rangeObjectRequest);
            System.out.println("Printing bytes retrieved.");
            displayTextInputStream(objectPortion.getObjectContent());

            // Get an entire object, overriding the specified response headers, and print the object's content.
            ResponseHeaderOverrides headerOverrides = new ResponseHeaderOverrides()
                    .withCacheControl("No-cache")
                    .withContentDisposition("attachment; filename=example.txt");
            GetObjectRequest getObjectRequestHeaderOverride = new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, key)
                    .withResponseHeaders(headerOverrides);
            headerOverrideObject = s3Client.getObject(getObjectRequestHeaderOverride);
            displayTextInputStream(headerOverrideObject.getObjectContent());
        } catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
            // The call was transmitted successfully, but Amazon S3 couldn't process 
            // it, so it returned an error response.
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SdkClientException e) {
            // Amazon S3 couldn't be contacted for a response, or the client
            // couldn't parse the response from Amazon S3.
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            // To ensure that the network connection doesn't remain open, close any open input streams.
            if (fullObject != null) {
                fullObject.close();
            }
            if (objectPortion != null) {
                objectPortion.close();
            }
            if (headerOverrideObject != null) {
                headerOverrideObject.close();
            }
        }
    }

    private static void displayTextInputStream(InputStream input) throws IOException {
        // Read the text input stream one line at a time and display each line.
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

The code above you can see that there is no close for `AmazonS3` client.
It is created by the `AwsClientBuilder`.

So.  when you creat the aws s3 client by `AwsClientBuilder` then it is no needed for close? why is it?

Thanks.

Comment: You do not need `s3.close()` in your code.
In [these examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/examples-s3-buckets.html), the client has been closed only in the case when the bucket has been deleted. Check the [documentation](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/S3Client.html) to learn more about it.

Comment: I didn't understand. First code has `close` method while the second code does not have it. I questioned why these two have differnece.

Comment: That's what I have mentioned. The `close` method call is not required in the first code. It's not doing any harm but it's not required.

Comment: Thanks. But in the code <https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/javav2/example_code/s3/src/main/java/com/example/s3/GetObjectData.java> which is official aws sdk reference, you can see the s3 client's close in the code.

Comment: I have corrected it on [github](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/pull/4203/commits/7e36a869adad8369d9dafe9deeef8fe5e68df48d). I hope it helps.